# Angular 5 - Catch connection lost and resubscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, connection, angular5, angular-services

I have this service asking my server every 5 seconds for data and it works just fine.
But if a connection is lost then I should tell my components that there is no internet connection until my connection comes back up. This is where my problem is, it seems in my response I get to cancel my previous request, and startup my next request, even if I don't have any internet connection.

How do I tell my components that the connection is lost while it is activity trying to reconnect and get data?

```
getOdometerData(id: any) {
const interval = 5000;
const source = Observable.timer(0, interval);
const url = `${this.api + '/' + id}`;
var getdata = this.http.get(url)
}).timeout(interval).retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(interval));
return source.switchMap(result => getdata).publishReplay(1).refCount();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can check internet connectivity using `navigator` :

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/net-connection)

try something like this:

```
  checkOnline() {
    if (navigator.onLine) {
      this.data = true
    } else {
      this.data = false
      alert("There is no connection")
    }
  }
```

and than do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option. I need to handle connection lost in my service and send that information my all my components. So my guess would be I need to send an observable to my components but I don't seem to be allowed to do so.

Comment: do you want to do that thing for all components??

Comment: For all relevant compontens, sure.

Comment: do u want to use intercepter??

Comment: Sure if I could catch connection lost, while still waiting for reconnect